# Is it possible to use django as a proxy for websoxket

Tags: django, websocket, proxy

I have a service (written in erlang) that accepts websocket connection from my django application. Django serves the page and the js script that makes the calls to the erlang service.

Now I want to go through the django server also for websocket connection and messaging. That is to use django as a proxy that forwards websocket connection and messages from the client to the Erlang service and sends back responses from the erlang service to the client. Optionally django should also check request authorization before forwarding them.

Is that possible?

Comment: Django isn't a web server, its a web framework